# Can not edit or add a user account on Mavericks Server App

Tags: macos, mac, server.app

I'm having a problem with the Server app on my Mac Mini.

I had to renew my Domain Name and DNS is now working well. But i can not edit existing user accounts or add new user accounts to my Server. The the + and - buttons to add or remove users are greyed out and it is not possible for me to edit something under this Service. And under the Server app it is not possible to add a Network user.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: It could be, that the domain, that referred to localhost can't connect to it's Open Directory any more, where all your accounts are. Maybe editing the hostfile helps. Also have a look at the workgroup manager. And also get a backup of the system if you don't have one already.

Comment: actually, can you connect to the server with an existing user ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the directions posted at: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200018

In summary:
1. Check that your DNS settings are correct using terminal `host` and `hostname` commands
2. Rekerberize your server - the steps basically reinitialize slapd and the chain of trust needed for network account operation